# jQuery UI datepicker onSelect NOT working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have `From Date` and `To Date` `jQuery datepicker` controls and if I change `From Date`, then `To Date` should automatically be `180 days` from `From Date`

Below code is not firing the `onSelect` event even if this looks so simple...

```
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (dateStr) {
            var newDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (newDate) {
                newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 180);
            }
            $('#txtTo').datepicker('setDate', newDate).datepicker('option', 'minDate', newDate);
        }
    });
```

Also, I require `onChange` event to be fired...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: jquery-ui version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your scenario. Hope this helps.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect:function(dateStr){
            var oldDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var newDate = new Date(oldDate.setMonth(oldDate.getMonth()+7))
            newDate=(newDate.getMonth()+1)+'/'+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+'/'+newDate.getFullYear()
            document.getElementById("datepicker1").value = newDate;
        }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>From_Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>To_Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a DatePicker icon next to the Text control. Also, currently, I cannot change the Year directly. I have to scroll through each month.

Comment: yes, you have to scroll to each month. That's how basic date picker works. But you can search for other date picker libraries in which you can scroll through the year. Hope this helps. Upvote if it's helpful.